# How does humanity survive after half of the population returns?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, realism, ending, avengers-infinity-war

In the Avengers the villain snaps his fingers and half the universe population disappears. Later, after several years have passed this half returns, effectively doubling the world population in one moment.

Is there any in-universe explanation of what happens in the mid-term after this? It seems to me that this would be an event with catastrophic consequences. The economy could hardly absorb an immediate doubling of people and it seems unlikely that the world, while struggling to cope with their loss a few years earlier, would have stockpiled 2x the annual food consumption.

In the real world I live in, I would expect global riots, food looting, famine, war, and widespread starvation. But in the films the only problems they address seem rather minor in comparison: emotional support groups and occasional disputes over home ownership.

What actually happens in the Avengers universe after the world population is immediately doubled?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe but I can't find it now.

Comment: OP is asking for an "in-universe explanation", so this cannot be opinion-based (but this does decrease the chance of an answer, I guess).

Comment: Hulk uses a lot of energy to do the snap to "bring everything back to normal". So all "normal" consequences can be handwaved away by "he created enough food from thin air so support all that recreated living forms"

Comment: @Joachim the problem is that there isn't an in-universe explanation... So it's anyone's guess.

Comment: Wow, -2 points on my very first question. I can only go up from here! :D The question seemed interesting to me, and it seemed in line with the rules on this site's [Don't Ask](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [What Topics Can I Ask About Here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages. Any tips on what I can do to improve my questions in the future?

Comment: Well, you're just quite succinctly showing it's a dumb movie, despite what you hope for. They should just turn back time and, yes, it was possible using time stone alone. It's just creators wanted stuff that happened to be impactful, just as impactful as *they* wanted, not how logic dictates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any in-universe explanation of what happens in the mid-term after this?

### No

> What actually happens in the Avengers universe after the world population is immediately doubled?

### We don't know.

Basically, we're presented with a *fait accompli* that everything just, essentially, reverted back to normal.

*Spider-Man: Far From Home* doesn't show us much of the aftermath of the Blip/UnSnap other than mentioning how people came back. There is no mention of the obvious problems that *should* have been caused by the sudden doubling of the worlds/universes' population after a 5 year gap, we just have to accept and move on.

It's **possible** that the Hulk "solved" the issue when he brought but we're not given any sight or indication that this actually happened.